# Gradle application plugin, run task doesn't fork process

Tags: java, gradle

I have the following project structure:

```
Root project 'rmi-tutorial'
+--- Project ':client'
+--- Project ':lib'
\--- Project ':server'
```

The execution order of my root-project is:

1. server
2. client

**What I want:**

1. lib gets compiled
2. server gets compiled and starts
3. client gets compiled and starts

**What I get:**

1. lib gets compiled
2. server gets compiled and starts
3. Server is running in endless loop because gradle doesnt fork the process
4. client will never run because gradle is waiting until the server run job succeeds that will not happen because it's a server. It's considered to run endless.

**My Question:**

How can I say gradle that gradle should fork run process of server?

Comment: The `run` task is of type `JavaExec` which is always executed in a separate process. Can you elaborate what you mean by "3. server is running in an endless loop..." One thing to keep in mind is, that the gradle blocks till the external process has finished. that might be your issue.

Comment: It's a RMI server that will never finish. http://fs5.directupload.net/images/170724/t6lrhiyz.png The task run for the subprojcet server runs endless because gradle doesn't fork the process and waits for a return code of the execution..